# Get access to the console once the console object reference was changed

Tags: javascript, firebug, greasemonkey, console.log

I like making userscripts. It's real fun to get some more control of your favorite page or just speed up it's loading.

Curently, I came across a problem that a page either defines console reference to a new dummy object:

```
window.console = {log: function() {}, info: function() {} ... };
```

Or it even destroys the functions:

```
window.console.log = function() {};
window.console.info = function() {};
...
```

<sup>I'm using `window` to make it obvious that I'm talking about the global scope. Also, I didn't use quick assigment to the same function on purpose, in the second example</sup>

Now how would you deal with this? Alerts work nice, but I've got used to Firebug and it's console quite a lot.
Can't express how graceful will I be for any help.

PNS.: Currently, the [League of Legends forums](http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com) is the site in question. Run the following code to see the problem:

```
window.console.log.toString(); //returns "function () {}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I've got one nasty solution here. Create an iframe (which creates new window) and get the console object of that iframe:

```
function healConsole() {
  //<iframe> element
  var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  //Hide it somewhere
  iframe.style.position="fixed";
  iframe.style.height = iframe.style.width = "1px";
  iframe.style.top = iframe.style.left = "-5px";
  //No src to prevent loading some data
  iframe.src = "about: blank";
  //Needs append to work
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  //Get the inner console
  window.console = iframe.contentWindow.console;
}
```

Not sure how cross browser is this though. I'm looking for something better...

Comment: That's probably as cross browser as you can get. With Chrome devtools you can also use the hack `delete console; delete console.log` (`log` lives on the prototype, and `console` is magic), and with Firefox devtools the hack `delete console` (`console` is even more magic). Firebug's console, however, isn't magic, so you can't get to it without a new global object. (Unless, of course, you can get your hands on `console` before it's overwritten.)

Comment: Thanks for these other options, I will try them now. I don't like the idea of creating an element (and espetially an iframe) just because of this.

Comment: You may also want to follow [issue 5995](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=5995) (Give a hint when Console API can't be injected) and [issue 6268](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=6268) (Expose a clean "console" object to the Command Line).