# Chrome "delete console" - how to restore it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, console.log

It's possible to restore chrome console after: `delete console`

Google Chrome version: 46.0.2490.80 m

In previous versions this command restore original console, but now I receive message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: console is not defined

Comment: it never even occurred to me to do this. it's hilarious that it's possible though. (sorry)

Comment: Why do you even want to do `delete console;`?

Comment: @Marino i'm going to go with "you can't". i can't find anything about it in Chrome's documentation, and it's probably constructed / hooked up in places you can't really get to from the javascript command console.
That leaves one solution : "Did you try turning it off and on again?" (just close down all chrome windows, then open a new one)

Comment: @AntiHeadshot One case is when you're making userscript and the site you're scripting intentionally deletes or overwrites console.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get access to the console once the console object reference was changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944457/get-access-to-the-console-once-the-console-object-reference-was-changed)

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's easy and it's already been asked:

```
function healConsole() {
  //<iframe> element
  var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  //Hide it somewhere
  iframe.style.position="fixed";
  iframe.style.height = iframe.style.width = "1px";
  iframe.style.top = iframe.style.left = "-5px";
  //No src to prevent loading some data
  iframe.src = "about: blank";
  //Needs append to work
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  //Get the inner console
  window.console = iframe.contentWindow.console;
}
```

Originally asked here: [Get access to the console once the console object reference was changed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21944457/607407)

Comment: It's already been asked in many places, but this doesn't work for Chrome 61 and up.  Other than the hacky alert() solution, nothing seems to work for the latest version of Chrome, probably for 'performance' reasons, but it makes developing/debugging very painful for sites that disable it and remove it from the prototype.