# Is it possible to log text that is typed in the browser's console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, xss

I made a function/object (functions and objects are like the same in Javascript)

```
function KeyLogger () {

    this.log = '';

    // http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes
    this.keymap = {
        8: 'backspace', 9: 'tab', 13: 'enter', 16: 'shift', 17: 'ctrl', 18: 'alt', 19: 'pause/break',
        20: 'caps lock', 27: 'escape', 33: 'page up', 34: 'page down', 35: 'end', 36: 'home', 37: 'left arrow',
        38: 'up arrow', 39: 'right arrow', 40: 'down arrow', 45: 'insert', 46: 'delete', 48: '0', 49: '1',
        50: '2', 51: '3', 52: '4', 53: '5', 54: '6', 55: '7', 56: '8', 57: '9', 65: 'a', 66: 'b', 67: 'c',
        68: 'd', 69: 'e', 70: 'f', 71: 'g', 72: 'h', 73: 'i', 74: 'j', 75: 'k', 76: 'l', 77: 'm', 78: 'n',
        79: '0', 80: 'p', 81: 'q', 82: 'r', 83: 's', 84: 't', 85: 'u', 86: 'v', 87: 'w', 88: 'x', 89: 'y',
        90: 'z', 91: 'left window key', 92: 'right window key', 93: 'select key', 96: 'numpad 0', 97: 'numpad 1',
        98: 'numpad 2', 99: 'numpad 3', 100: 'numpad 4', 101: 'numpad 5', 102: 'numpad 6', 103: 'numpad 7',
        104: 'numpad 8', 105: 'numpad 9', 106: 'multiply', 107: 'add', 109: 'subtract', 110: 'decimal point',
        111: 'divide', 112: 'f1', 113: 'f2', 114: 'f3', 115: 'f4', 116: 'f5', 117: 'f6', 118: 'f7', 119: 'f8',
        120: 'f9', 121: 'f10', 122: 'f11', 123: 'f12', 144: 'num lock', 145: 'scroll lock', 186: 'semi-colon',
        187: 'equal sign', 188: 'comma', 189: 'dash', 190: 'period', 191: 'forward slash', 192: 'grave accent',
        219: 'open bracket', 220: 'back slash', 221: 'close bracket', 222: 'single quote'
    };

    this.addKey = function (k) {
        // k : key code
        if (k in this.keymap) this.log += this.keymap[k] + ' ,';
    }

    this.clearLog = function () {
        this.log = '';
    }
 }
```

to log keys that are typed. This was meant as a security measure on my site. Of course, I'm mainly interested in what, if anything, is typed in the console. Since it took me a long time to manually write out t`his.keymap`, I'm hoping I didn't waste my time. But when I tested my page and typed stuff in the console, it wasn't logged, whereas if I'm clicked on the `body` itself and type, it is logged. Is there any possible way I can get stuff typed into the console????

Comment: javascript keyloggers: coming soon to an OS near you.

Comment: Sure - implement your own browser and log whatever is typed... Otherwise it is really hard to get your code do anything when your code does not run at all.

Comment: What ever you code in your site has a scope of window. Console is not part of your window, so no you cannot do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get access to the console once the console object reference was changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944457/get-access-to-the-console-once-the-console-object-reference-was-changed)

Comment: This is nowhere near to a duplicate of that question, so the first two close votes are way off target.

Answer (score 0):

Like [Rajesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3783478/rajesh) says, Javascript code running in your browser is scoped to the window.  And since the console runs separately from the window, your Javascript cannot directly access it.

So no, it is not possible to log the text that the user is typing into their Javascript console.

Having said that, if the user calls functions from the console, and you have the opportunity to override those functions, then you could learn a little bit about what the user is doing.

As a proof of concept, add the following Javascript to the page:

```
var myLog = "";

var realSetTimeout = window.setTimeout;

window.setTimeout = function(a, b){
    myLog += "setTimeout was called from " + (new Error).stack + "\n";
    myLog += "with arguments: " + a + " and " + b + "\n";

    return realSetTimeout.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Now if the user was to run `setTimeout(function)({ test; }, 1000);` from their console, your `myLog` variable would contain something like this:

**Chrome**

```
setTimeout was called from Error
    at window.setTimeout (<anonymous>:3:51)
    at <anonymous>:2:1
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:875:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:808:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:664:21)
with arguments: function (){ test; } and 1000
```

**Firefox**

```
setTimeout was called from window.setTimeout@debugger eval code:2:51
@debugger eval code:1:1
with arguments: function (){ test; } and 1000
```

(Of course the code above would also log every call to setTimeout made from the normal page scripts too!  So you might want to log only those with a matching stacktrace.)

So it is in fact possible to spy on the user's console commands a little bit, if the user call functions.

Perhaps using getters you could also spy on property accesses.

Whether your users will appreciate you doing this, or whether you will gain any useful information from it, is another matter!